# Difficulties deserializing XML using Rust and Serde where document has optional subelements

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I'm very new to Rust, and am still trying to get the hang of working with it. It's cool, but I'm clearly missing something with an exercise I gave myself. For reference, I'm using rustc 1.39.0.

I wanted to try to write a simple program to read the XML from MSBuild's code analysis, which outputs some fairly simple XML. The problem I think is that there is an element (`PATH`) which is *usually* empty, but sometimes can contain elements under it. The bigger problem is that I suck at Rust (and I don't usually deal with XML), and I'm not really sure how to correctly set up the structs I need for deserialization. I'm using Serde and quick_xml. When I had `PATH` set as a String and worked with XML that did not have an SFA element under PATH, my tests worked. But once I figured out how that tag was *supposed* to be used and updated my structs accordingly, I constantly get the error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom("missing field `FILEPATH`")', src\libcore\result.rs:1165:5
```

...even if *all* of the defects in the test XML file have SFA element under PATH.

The XML files I'm dealing with all look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DEFECTS>
  <DEFECT>
    <SFA>
      <FILEPATH>c:\projects\source\repos\defecttest\defecttest</FILEPATH>
      <FILENAME>source.cpp</FILENAME>
      <LINE>8</LINE>
      <COLUMN>5</COLUMN>
    </SFA>
    <DEFECTCODE>26496</DEFECTCODE>
    <DESCRIPTION>The variable 'y' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4).</DESCRIPTION>
    <FUNCTION>main</FUNCTION>
    <DECORATED>main</DECORATED>
    <FUNCLINE>6</FUNCLINE>
    <PATH></PATH>
  </DEFECT>
  <DEFECT>
    <SFA>
      <FILEPATH>c:\projects\source\repos\defecttest\defecttest</FILEPATH>
      <FILENAME>source.cpp</FILENAME>
      <LINE>9</LINE>
      <COLUMN>5</COLUMN>
    </SFA>
    <DEFECTCODE>26496</DEFECTCODE>
    <DESCRIPTION>The variable 'z' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4).</DESCRIPTION>
    <FUNCTION>main</FUNCTION>
    <DECORATED>main</DECORATED>
    <FUNCLINE>6</FUNCLINE>
    <PATH></PATH>
  </DEFECT>
</DEFECTS>
```

In many cases, `PATH` is empty, but in some it contains its own `SFA` element:

```
  <DEFECT>
    <SFA>
      <FILEPATH>c:\projects\source\repos\defecttest\defecttest</FILEPATH>
      <FILENAME>source.cpp</FILENAME>
      <LINE>9</LINE>
      <COLUMN>5</COLUMN>
    </SFA>
    <DEFECTCODE>26496</DEFECTCODE>
    <DESCRIPTION>The variable 'z' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4).</DESCRIPTION>
    <FUNCTION>main</FUNCTION>
    <DECORATED>main</DECORATED>
    <FUNCLINE>6</FUNCLINE>
    <PATH>
      <SFA>
        <FILEPATH>c:\projects\source\repos\defecttest\defecttest</FILEPATH>
        <FILENAME>source.cpp</FILENAME>
        <LINE>12</LINE>
        <COLUMN>3</COLUMN>
      </SFA>
    </PATH>
  </DEFECT>
```

Before I realized this, all of the fields in the DEFECT struct were set to String. That works correctly, assuming none of the defects in the XML file have subelements under PATH. When I changed it to SFA instead of String, it gives me the missing field error mentioned above. An example of the code I'm testing with:

**main.rs**

```
extern crate quick_xml;
extern crate serde;

use std::default::Default;
use std::env;
use std::vec::Vec;

use quick_xml::de::from_str;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

/*
 * Structs for the defect XML
 */

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct DEFECTS {
    #[serde(rename = "DEFECT", default)]
    pub defects: Vec<DEFECT>,
}

#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct DEFECT {
    #[serde(default)]
    pub SFA: SFA,
    pub DEFECTCODE: String,
    pub DESCRIPTION: String,
    pub FUNCTION: String,
    pub DECORATED: String,
    pub FUNCLINE: String,
    #[serde(default)]
    pub PATH: Vec<SFA>,
}

#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct SFA {
    pub FILEPATH: String,
    pub FILENAME: String,
    pub LINE: String,
    pub COLUMN: String,
}

/*
 * Main app code
 */

fn main() {
    // Expect the path to the XML file to be passed as the first and only argument
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() != 2 {
        panic!("Invalid argument count. Specify a single file to process.");
    }

    let processing_file = &args[1];
    println!("Will attempt to process file: '{}'", &processing_file);

    // Try to load the contents of the file
    let file_content : String = match std::fs::read_to_string(&processing_file) {
        Ok(file_content) => file_content,
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("Failed to read file: '{}' -- {}", &processing_file, e);
        }
    };

    // Now, try to deserialize the XML we have in file_content
    let defect_list : DEFECTS = from_str(&file_content).unwrap();

    // Assuming the unwrap above didn't blow up, we should get a count here
    println!("Retrieved {} defects from file '{}'", defect_list.defects.len(), &processing_file);
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "rust_xml_test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["fny82"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
quick-xml = { version = "0.17", features = [ "serialize" ] }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = [ "derive" ] }
```

**Example output**

```
C:\Development\RustXmlTest>cargo run -- "c:\development\rustxmltest\test3.xml"
   Compiling rust_xml_test v0.1.0 (C:\Development\RustXmlTest)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.56s
     Running `target\debug\rust_xml_test.exe c:\development\rustxmltest\test3.xml`
Will attempt to process file: 'c:\development\rustxmltest\test3.xml'
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom("missing field `FILEPATH`")', src\libcore\result.rs:1165:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\rust_xml_test.exe c:\development\rustxmltest\test3.xml` (exit code: 101)
```

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, and part of that is probably that I'm getting ahead of myself with respect to the scope of the challenge vs. my current level of comprehension of working with Rust. Can anyone give me a hand in sorting out what I'm missing and doing wrong?

Somewhat related: I've since learned that I can use the `rename` property in order to have my structs comply with Rust's naming conventions, but for now I didn't want to start messing with that until I got the underlying functionality working.

**---- EDIT ----**

For reference, with the correction from @edwardw the now-working code:

```
extern crate quick_xml;
extern crate serde;

use std::default::Default;
use std::env;
use std::vec::Vec;

use quick_xml::de::from_str;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

/*
 * Structs for the defect XML
 */

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct DEFECTS {
    #[serde(rename = "DEFECT", default)]
    pub defects: Vec<DEFECT>,
}

#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct DEFECT {
    #[serde(default)]
    pub SFA: SFA,
    pub DEFECTCODE: String,
    pub DESCRIPTION: String,
    pub FUNCTION: String,
    pub DECORATED: String,
    pub FUNCLINE: String,
    pub PATH: PATH,
}

#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct SFA {
    pub FILEPATH: String,
    pub FILENAME: String,
    pub LINE: String,
    pub COLUMN: String,
}

#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct PATH {
    pub SFA: Option<SFA>,
}

/*
 * Main app code
 */

fn main() {
    // Expect the path to the XML file to be passed as the first and only argument
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() != 2 {
        panic!("Invalid argument count. Specify a single file to process.");
    }

    let processing_file = &args[1];
    println!("Will attempt to process file: '{}'", &processing_file);

    // Try to load the contents of the file
    let file_content : String = match std::fs::read_to_string(&processing_file) {
        Ok(file_content) => file_content,
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("Failed to read file: '{}' -- {}", &processing_file, e);
        }
    };

    // Now, try to deserialize the XML we have in file_content
    let defect_list : DEFECTS = from_str(&file_content).unwrap();

    // Assuming the unwrap above didn't blow up, we should get a count here
    println!("Retrieved {} defects from file '{}'", defect_list.defects.len(), &processing_file);
}
```

Example:

```
C:\Development\RustXmlTest>cargo run -- "c:\development\rustxmltest\test1.xml"
   Compiling rust_xml_test v0.1.0 (C:\Development\RustXmlTest)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.66s
     Running `target\debug\rust_xml_test.exe c:\development\rustxmltest\test1.xml`
Will attempt to process file: 'c:\development\rustxmltest\test1.xml'
Retrieved 2 defects from file 'c:\development\rustxmltest\test1.xml'
```

where test1.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DEFECTS>
  <DEFECT>
    <SFA>
      <FILEPATH>c:\projects\source\repos\defecttest\defecttest</FILEPATH>
      <FILENAME>source.cpp</FILENAME>
      <LINE>8</LINE>
      <COLUMN>5</COLUMN>
    </SFA>
    <DEFECTCODE>26496</DEFECTCODE>
    <DESCRIPTION>The variable 'y' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4).</DESCRIPTION>
    <FUNCTION>main</FUNCTION>
    <DECORATED>main</DECORATED>
    <FUNCLINE>6</FUNCLINE>
    <PATH></PATH>
  </DEFECT>
  <DEFECT>
    <SFA>
      <FILEPATH>c:\projects\source\repos\defecttest\defecttest</FILEPATH>
      <FILENAME>source.cpp</FILENAME>
      <LINE>9</LINE>
      <COLUMN>5</COLUMN>
    </SFA>
    <DEFECTCODE>26496</DEFECTCODE>
    <DESCRIPTION>The variable 'z' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4).</DESCRIPTION>
    <FUNCTION>main</FUNCTION>
    <DECORATED>main</DECORATED>
    <FUNCLINE>6</FUNCLINE>
    <PATH>
      <SFA>
        <FILEPATH>c:\projects\source\repos\defecttest\defecttest</FILEPATH>
        <FILENAME>source.cpp</FILENAME>
        <LINE>12</LINE>
        <COLUMN>3</COLUMN>
      </SFA>
    </PATH>
  </DEFECT>
</DEFECTS>
```

Comment: look like a bug, I don't know if xml allow empty array but I think it should maybe look if an issue for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PATH` itself should be modeled as a struct with one optional field. This works:

```rust
#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct DEFECT {
    #[serde(default)]
    pub SFA: SFA,
    pub DEFECTCODE: String,
    pub DESCRIPTION: String,
    pub FUNCTION: String,
    pub DECORATED: String,
    pub FUNCLINE: String,
    pub PATH: PATH,
}

#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct PATH {
    SFA: Option<SFA>,
}
```

Comment: Ah, Option, of course! I never thought of using that here. This does indeed solve the problem. Thank you!